# Convert an entire column from character to date class in R

Tags: r, dplyr, strptime

I am using this [dataset](https://data.baltimorecity.gov/Public-Safety/BPD-Arrests/3i3v-ibrt) and I am looking to convert the ArrestDate column from character in to dates so that I can work with dates for analysis.

I've first tried using mutate:

```
Date <- mutate(crime, ArrestDate = as.Date(ArrestDate, format= "%d.%m.%Y"))
```

however when I do this the entire ArrestDate column is changed to NAs.

Secondly I tried using strptime but for some reason it converts some dates fine and others to NA:

```
Date <-strptime(paste(crime$ArrestDate, sep=" "),"%d/%m/%Y")
crime2 <- cbind(Date, crime)
```

Anyone able to tell me what I am doing wrong or alternatively provide a better approach for this?
Thanks.

Comment: seems like its `month/day/year` format. Maybe you just need to modify your code a bit

Comment: Hi @FrankZhang thanks that worked for method 2 as the month and date were the wrong way around, however the mutate function did the same thing as before after I corrected the date format. Any idea what's wrong with that particular code?

Comment: if you pass the same format `%m/%d/%Y` to your first line of code. It should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the '.' with '/' works from your first example in the format:

```
Date <- mutate(crime, ArrestDate = as.Date(ArrestDate, format= "%m/%d/%Y"))
class(Date$ArrestDate)
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: if you use %y instead of %Y you take only the first two digits of the string and all years (2017, 2019 etc) will become 2020.

Comment: nice point - updated.

Answer (score 4):

The lubridate package offers some very useful functions to transform strings into dates. In this case you can use `mdy()` since the format is '%m/%d/%Y' (as can be derived from the first record which is '12/31/2019').

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

crime %>% 
  mutate(ArrestDate = mdy(ArrestDate))
```